# How do I change the exchange rate base currency with exchangeratesapi.io and okhttp, and have all of the base currencies in a spinner to select from?

Tags: java, android, api, currency

What I want to do is change the exchange rate base(that is euro by default) to any other currency, and have them all in a spinner like the currency I'm changing to, so the user could select any base currency and the currency to convert to with a spinner.

Likes so here, but for the base currency

[image]

Here is my code

```
public static BreakIterator data;
    List<String> keysList;
    Spinner toCurrency;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toCurrency = findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
        final EditText edtEuroValue = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        final Button btnConvert = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        try {
            //From the API loads the conversion types from a url and makes a request(gets all of the currencies)
            loadConversionTypes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //If the inserted currency to convert from is not empty the program will initialize the toCurency(will get the
                //selected item and then will get the double value of the currency to convert from(weird as hell ik)
                if(!edtEuroValue.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    String toCurr = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    double euroValue = Double.valueOf(edtEuroValue.getText().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calculating..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        //calls the convertCurrency() method and takes in the parameters of the currrency to convert to, and the
                        //currency to convert from(2nd paramter)
                        convertCurrency(toCurr, euroValue);
                    }
                    //will catch an error if the conversion doesn't work
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                //If the value of the currency to convert from is empty, it will show a message:
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a value first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void loadConversionTypes() throws IOException {

        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();


        //passes in parameter request from the api(code above)
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                //takes the failure message and displays it as a toast
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                final String mMessage = response.body().string();


                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                            JSONObject b = obj.getJSONObject("rates"); //b is a collection of rate data
                            //JSONObject base = obj.getJSONObject("base");

                            Iterator keysToCopyIterator = b.keys(); //the Iterator gets all of the data from the b rates and
                                                                    //stores it in keysToCopyIterator
                            //a new scalable ArrayList of keys is created, the keys are stored as strings
                            keysList = new ArrayList<String>();

                            //while the key iterator keeps returning true for any tokens to be scanned it will keep on checking
                            //for the next keys possible until it returns false(all tokens have been scanned)
                            while(keysToCopyIterator.hasNext()) {

                                //finds and returns the complete key and saves it a string, which is later saved to an arraylist
                                String key = (String) keysToCopyIterator.next();

                                //adds the key to the ArrayList
                                keysList.add(key);

                            }


                            //An ArrayAdapter is created and sets all of the currencies(keysLists or exchange rates) to the spinner
                            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, keysList );
                            toCurrency.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); //the to currency spinner is set to the adapter






                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }




        });
    }

    public void convertCurrency(final String toCurr, final double euroValue) throws IOException {

        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();



        //catches execption incase of failure or error
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                final String mMessage = response.body().string();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                            JSONObject  b = obj.getJSONObject("rates");

                            String val = b.getString(toCurr);

                            double output = /*selected currency */euroValue*Double.valueOf(val);


                            textView.setText(String.valueOf(output));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }





        });
    }
}
```

Don't mind the comments I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn to code and comment everything out 
If you can't help me, then maybe you could find the documentation for how to do it, I've been looking around everywhere and can't find the proper java code for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since noone answered I came up with my own solution.

I created 2 spinners and called them baseCurrency and toCurrency and then
what I did was this - I created another spinner and then set the spinner adapter to it `baseCurrency.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);`

and then in convertCurrency() I put in these 2 lines

```
String fromCurrVal = b.getString(baseCurrency);
double output = baseValue/Double.valueOf(frommCurrVal)*Double.valueOf(val);
```

This here gets the base value of the number that is inputed divides it by the selected currency rate and then times it by the value of the currency you want to convert to.
Kind of confusing but it gets the job done and very efficiently.